# How to write select query along with IF condition in place of column name in mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.receipt,
if(SELECT status FROM list WHERE receipt = o.receipt GROUP BY receipt) as status 
FROM orderlist o
```

What is the correct way to write the above query **If condition** and get result like below example.

Same receipt(orderId) has more than one tuple(row) and **all this tuple might have different status value**.And I want to set value as per receipt(orderId) first tuple status using IF statement.

`IF(status = 'shipped', "Yes", "NO");`

Comment: Try to use case statement.

Comment: How?Give an simple example..

Comment: Why not to use join?

Comment: Provide a example table with example data en expected results.

Comment: This return only one tuple because of GROUP BY clause. I have already tried.

Comment: Only problem is that status can be unrelated to the grouped receipt.  https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: Agreed will only return 1 value but status will be indeterminate. Are you trying to get the most recent status?

Comment: Same receipt has more than one tuple(row) and all this tuple has different status value.And I want to set value as per receipt first tuple status Using IF statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you data model looks like this (ie you have a way of distinguishing the order of events) then a limit in your subquery might do.

```
drop table if exists t,t1;

create table t(id int);
create table t1(id int, tid int, status varchar(10));

insert into t values (1),(2);
insert into t1 values (1,1,'a'),(2,1,'Shipped'),(3,1,'Returned'), (4,2,'shipped');

select t.id,
         if(
         (select status from t1 where t1.tid = t.id order by id limit 1)
         = 'Shipped','yes','no') shipped
from t;
```

Result

```
+------+---------+
| id   | shipped |
+------+---------+
|    1 | no      |
|    2 | yes     |
+------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But isn't shipment usually the last status?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.receipt, CASE status when 'Shipped' then 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as status 
FROM orderlist o join receipt r on o.receipt = r.receipt
```